# InitWithStyle, awakeFromNib не нужны?

Tags: xcode, ios

При создании класса вместе с ним автоматически создаются некоторые методы. Например, initWithStyle, awakeFromNib и другие. Ведь при использовании storyboard'ов они нужны? Их можно смело удалять?

Comment: @Troir, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем вы видите проблему, как ее воспроизвести и т. д.

Answer (score 1):

awakeFromNib вызывается, например, для UITableViewCell и UICollectionViewCell даже если они заданы как prototype/static cells в storyboard. Также они будут вызваны для любого кастомного UIView/UIControl сабкласса, который вы используете в UIViewController, собранном в storyboard. Нужны они вам или нет - решать вам, но это неплохой коллбек для какой-либо инициализации после загрузки объекта из xib/storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

Если они вам не нужны, то можете удалить.